# Валидация формы обратной связи

Tags: javascript, валидация

Доброго дня!

Делаю форму обратной связи и столкнулся с 2 проблемами:

1) валидация номера телефона

```
[CODE]
case 'cont_phone':
                    var cont_phone = /^([0-9)/;
                           if(val != '' && cont_phone.test(val))
                           {
                              $(this).addClass('not_error').css('border',bcolorGreen);
                           }
                           else
                           {
                              $(this).removeClass('not_error').addClass('error').css('border',bcolorRed);
                    }
                    break;
[/CODE]
```

Не работает скрипт... именно, не сверяет с цифрами;

2) как сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "отправить" проверялись на заполнение все поля, и если одно из них не заполнено, выдавалось ошибка?

Comment: @alglu65, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 2):

В регулярке  `var cont_phone = /^([0-9)/;` нет закрывающей квадратной скобки.

[> 2) как сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "отправить" проверялось на заполнение все поля и если одно из них не заполнено - выдавалось ошибка?](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

Answer (score 0):

> как сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки
> "отправить" проверялось на заполнение
> все поля и если одно из них не
> заполнено - выдавалось ошибка?

Повесьте на форму событие

```
    $('form').submit(
       function(){ 
         .. код вашей валидации...
         если проходит валидацию return true
         если нет то return false и сообщение об ошибке }
    )
```

Или можно сделать на сервеной стороне в php.

Comment: На сервере не можно, а нужно проверять обязательно.

Comment: Да, обязательно нужно сделать и на сервере.